# Visiting Webpage ONLY after another page was visited. Possible?

Tags: pages, cookies

I am looking for a way to solve the following problem:

User should only be able to visit `mywebsite.com/page2/` after they visited `mywebsite.com/page1/`

If a user was not on page1, s/he should not be able to visit page2.

Is this possible?

Further specification: On page1 should be a survey (plugin: "Contact Form 7") and people are redirected to page2 after submitting their answers.

Comment: You could also use https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces in the url.

Answer (score 2):

You could set a cookie upon contact form submission, then check for the cookie on `/page2`. If it is not found, `wp_safe_redirect()` back to `/page1`.

[Setting a cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) - You will need to hook into Contact Form 7's submission - look into their documentation:

```
<?php
setcookie( 'my_cookies_name', true, 0 ); // This cookie will expire after the session
?>
```

Retreiving the cookie (on `/page2`'s php template:

```
<?php
if( is_page('page2') ) {
    // Because the value is set to true, you can just check for the value in if()
    if( ! $_COOKIE['my_cookies_name'] ) {
        // cookie isn't found, redirect back
        wp_safe_redirect( site_url('/page1') );
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Sounds good! :)

Comment: How can I set the cookie?

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: As far as I see, I have to set the cookie in the functions-template of the contact form 7 plugin. But where I don't get, where and how I can retrieve the cookie on the second page? To make it clearer: Where do I have to insert the second code snippet?

Comment: You can enter it into your `functions.php` file. with a `if( is_page( 'page2' )` if statement wrapped around it. Or you can create a template for `page2`. Duplicate the `page.php` file within your Theme, and call it `page-page2_slug.php` where page2_slug is the page's actual slug.

Comment: Example is now in my answer